# How to automatically log G Suite (Gmail) emails to Salesforce Contacts, Leads, and Accounts?

Tags: email, sync, gmail

Is there a way to automatically (without user interaction) log emails sent/received  as Email records in Sales Cloud to the corresponding Contacts, Leads, and Accounts?

Lightning Sync only handles Contacts and Events. The Salesforce Chrome extension doesn't automatically log emails; you have to choose which ones to log. Looking for something that hands free.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Salesforce Inbox](https://www.salesforce.com/form/demo/salesforce-inbox-email-demo/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIwPTDiKaF4wIVlcpkCh0-iAnoEAAYASAAEgLY0PD_BwE&d=7010M000000mkbg&nc=7010M000000uiwn&DCMP=KNC-Google&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMIwPTDiKaF4wIVlcpkCh0-iAnoEAAYASAAEgLY0PD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4604!3!189989915185!e!!g!!salesforce%20inbox&pcrid=189989915185&pdv=c) for that. It is a paid extra feature but it does exactly what you want it to do.

You do have to add the contacts/leads to salesforce (but the extension makes it really easy). Once you do that, the emails flow into Salesforce automatically.